# various axios call relative at previous one

Tags: node.js

i have an array of variable number of urls and i must merge the data get with axion

the problem is then every axios call is relative to the data of the previus

if i have a fixed number of ulrs i can nest axion calls and live with that

i think to use something like this

```
var urls = ["xx", "xx", "xx"];
mergeData(urls);

function mergeData(myarray, myid = 0, mydata = "none") {
    var myurl = "";
    if (Array.isArray(mydata)) {
        myurl = myarray[myid];
        // do my stuff with data and modify the url
    } else {
        myurl = myarray[myid];
    }
    axios.get(myurl)
        .then(response => {
            // do my stuff and get the data i need and put on an array
            if (myarray.length < myid) {
                mergeData(myarray, myid + 1, data);
            } else {
                // show result on ui
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

but i dont like it

there is another solution?

(be kind, i'm still learning ^^)

just to be clear
i need to optain

http request to "first url", parse the the json, save some data(some needed for the output)

another http request to "second url" with one or more parameter from previous data, parse the the json, save some data(some needed for the output)

... and so on, for 5 to 10 times

Comment: How are your axios calls relative to previous one?

Comment: Your first `if` statement doesn't really make sense since you're doing the same exact thing for your condition and the `else` statement - `myurl = myarray[myid];`. Also, this looks like you're trying to recursively make `HTTP` requests. There's a better way to go about this but I am unclear what the input is and what the expected output is supposed to be. An example would be great.

Comment: @Rashomon like in the code example, i loop the function till the end of urls array passing the data from previous calls and modify the urls according that data, its the only solution i can think, i cant do one call at time because the async nature of axios, i must nest them on the response

Comment: @goto1 the if statement its just an example because if "data" its an array(mean i am in loop 2++) i use that values to modify "myurl" and at the end of loop i will have all data i need in the array "data" so i can output them on ui

Comment: Right, but what are you trying to do exactly? Are you relying on `axios.get` call #1 to call #2? Or are you just trying to make HTTP calls to all URLs and then just return a single response after they all completed? Also, which version of `Node.js` are you using?

Comment: @goto1  yes i just try to make HTTP calls to all URLs recursive and get needed data from each call( and modify urls according the previous calls response data) before output them on ui  ... my english its not great so maybe i cant explain very well what i must obtain ^^ .... i use the latest stable version of nodejs

Comment: @andrea got it, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make subsequent HTTP calls based on information you get from previous calls, I'd utilize `async/await` and `for...of` to accomplish this instead of relying on a recursive solution.

```js
async function mergeData(urls) {
  const data = [];

  for (const url of urls) {
    const result = await axios.get(url).then(res => res.data);

    console.log(`[${result.id}] ${result.title}`);

    // here, do whatever you want to do with
    // `result` to make your next call...
    // for now, I am just going to append each
    // item to `data` and return it at the end

    data.push(result);
  }

  return data;
}

const items = [
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2",
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3"
];

console.log("fetching...")

mergeData(items)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log("done!")
    console.log("final result", result);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Using `async/await` allows you to utilize `for...of` which will wait for each call to `resolve` or `reject` before moving onto the next one.

To learn more about `async/await` and `for...of`, have a look here:

- [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Hope this helps.